# Snom 7xx devices bulk setup through FreePBX with custom template

Tags: asterisk, freepbx

Can someone teach me how to deploy multilple Snom 7xx series desktop mobiles in bulk (like 150) at once using FreePBX system with custom device settings (templates). As I am very new to this. Specially setting templates and where to place in Centos 6.2 FreePBX SYSTEM to auto provission...etc. 
I asked so much in one question

Yes here is the updated question detail:
I have created one extension for snom710 model, I want to make a template settings using that test extension but after clicking on edit template it shows some files, don't know which one to edit and which one serve for what purpose. And also if I want to control some of the settings using PBX then how to make that working, say for example **`<user_host idx="1" perm="">{$server.ip.1}</user_host>`**  what is this {$server.ip.1} I have seen this in my other snom model configured by freelancer for testing purpose.
attached is the screen shot.[image]

Thanks.

Comment: This site is for questions/answer, not for teaching. Can recommend you go upwork.com and find linux teacher.

Comment: Sorry for using the word "teach", I meant to say guide. Can some one guide me to the correct way.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the End Point Manager (EPM) to bulk configure your devices. It is a commercial modules.

Alternatively, if you want to do it yourself, you can build an auto provisioning server and configure your devices to download the config from the server. All Snom devices support auto provisioning out of the box. You can also put the auto provisioning server IP into DHCP option 66 so that your device can pick up the config automatically as soon as you connects it into your network.

A complete user guide can be found from the following. https://wiki.freepbx.org/display/FPG/EPM-Admin+User+Guide

Snom devices auto provisioning user guide. http://wiki.snom.com/Category:Auto_Provisioning

------------------------------------------------------------EDIT----------------------------------------------------------------

Definition of User host

> Specify the IP or DNS address of the registrar/proxy where you want to register this account. After a successful registration, the registrar knows how to reach this speciﬁc identity and can route requests (e.g., incoming calls) from other registered parties to this phone.

http://wiki.snom.com/Settings/user_host

Definitions of all other settings can be found from their wiki.

Comment: **Willow Yang**, Thanks for your suggestion but I have different models of snom, like 300 710 and 340. To control different templates I have no idea of it. Thanks please guide me to the correct way with snap shot. **My FreePBX version is 2.10.1.2**

Comment: Have you look at the link that I provided? It shows you everything you need to know to setup the templates for all types of phones including snom. If that is too much reading for you, there is a video you can watch. It might be easier to begin with. Check it out the video from this link [https://www.freepbx.org/endpoint-manager/](https://www.freepbx.org/endpoint-manager/)

Comment: **Willow Yang**, I just changed my question, could you please see that and advise on the same.

Comment: **Willow Yang*, Sorry I don't see your updates, please see my updated question and let me know which files to modify for the configuration, I mean I got multiple files there, just point me to the correct one or tell me for what purpose are those files in the picture. please.

Comment: I am not your personal teacher. all i can do is point you to the right direction. You got to do some research by yourself. The snom wiki and FreePBX documentation is a very good starting point.

Comment: **Willow Yang**, Thanks alot.